# Getting account's device list in Oreo

Tags: java, android, google-api, user-accounts

I attempt to get accounts list on the android device with the following code:

```
listOfAccounts    =   new ArrayList();
Pattern gmailPattern = Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS;
Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(this).getAccounts();
for (int x = 0; x < accounts.length; x++)
{
    if ( gmailPattern.matcher( accounts[ x ].name ).matches() )
    {
        if ( !_inArray( listOfAccounts, accounts[ x ].name ) )
        {
            listOfAccounts.add( accounts[ x ].name );
        }
    }
}
```

And this code works in every device I tried in **except** in a 
**Xiaomi Mi Note 2** with `Android 8.1`.
At first I thought it was a "filter" problem, because I used to select only Android accounts but it doesn't get any account at all.
Permissions are managed correctly since I've tried in already 5 devices and in everyone it works fine.

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to use `AccountManager.newChooseAccountIntent()` method.
Check the *Account access and discoverability* section in the [Android Developer site](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes)